# Why can't initiate events from the band?

Tags: mobile, background, listener, tile, microsoft-band

I've been playing around with the Microsoft Band SDK for a week or so.  I got my HR showing on my custom app, I have start and stop buttons triggering MP3 playing on my phone.  So now the question I ask myself is, "Ok lets make useful band applications..."

Well it appears you can't do much from the band, which makes it pretty much useless to develop for...If I have to launch a phone app just to get input from the band, that defeats the purpose, I will just use the phone app.

They really need to have a very lightweight listener on the phone for band events to trigger application launching.

Thoughts on workarounds?

Answer (score -1):

What type of phone are you developing for? On Android at least, you could make an application on the phone that has almost no UI but is completely controlled via the band using tile events and a service that handles their broadcasts. With just that, there are hundreds of possibilities.

Comment: Windows Phone 10 Lumia 950XL